# How to update OpenSSL from 1.0.0 to 1.0.1 in Windows 10?

Tags: openssl, updating, chatterbot

Thank you for taking the time to help me with my issue. I have recently stumbled upon ChatterBot, a Python library that enables the creation of chatbots capable of engaging in natural language conversations. That being said I am still relatively new to programming, and am struggling to get the example code to run. I am using **Python 3.7**, and coding in **Visual Studio Code.**

#### Requirements

The requirements have been installed with, `pip install -r Chatterbot-masters/requirements.txt`:

```
mathparse>=0.1,<0.2
python-dateutil>=2.8,<2.9
sqlalchemy>=1.3,<1.4
pytz
```

#### Example.py

I then duplicated the example code below.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer


# Create a new instance of a ChatBot
bot = ChatBot(
    'Example Bot',
    storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
    logic_adapters=[
        {
            'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.BestMatch',
            'default_response': 'I am sorry, but I do not understand.',
            'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.90
        }
    ]
)

trainer = ListTrainer(bot)

# Train the chat bot with a few responses
trainer.train([
    'How can I help you?',
    'I want to create a chat bot',
    'Have you read the documentation?',
    'No, I have not',
    'This should help get you started: http://chatterbot.rtfd.org/en/latest/quickstart.html'
])

# Get a response for some unexpected input
response = bot.get_response('How do I make an omelette?')
print(response)
```

#### Error

```
PS C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\Kindra> python example.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "example.py", line 13, in <module>
    'maximum_similarity_threshold': 0.90
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 28, in __init__        
    self.storage = utils.initialize_class(storage_adapter, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\utils.py", line 33, in initialize_class     
    return Class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\sql_storage.py", line 20, in __init__
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 23, in __init__
    'tagger_language', languages.ENG
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 20, in __init__
    import spacy
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .cli.info import info as cli_info
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .download import download  # noqa: F401
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\spacy\cli\download.py", line 5, in <module>
    import requests
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 39, in <module>
    "urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently "
ImportError: urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018. See: https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/2168
```

#### Troubleshooting Progress

##### OpenSSL Debug

1. I have tried to debug OpenSSL:

```
python -m OpenSSL.debug
>>
pyOpenSSL: 23.1.1
cryptography: 40.0.2
cffi: 1.15.1
cryptography's compiled against OpenSSL: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
cryptography's linked OpenSSL: OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
Python's OpenSSL: OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018
Python executable: C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
Python version: 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)]
Platform: win32
sys.path: ['C:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop\\Kindra', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\python37.zip', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\DLLs', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37', 'C:\\Users\\Joe\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37\\lib\\site-packages']
```

2. In addition when I run `python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"`:
   `OpenSSL 1.1.0h  27 Mar 2018`

##### Updating OpenSSL

I have downloaded "Win64 OpenSSL v1.1.1t" from https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html.

> I followed the prompts from the installer, not making any changes.

> I then extracted the "bin" folder and pasted it to "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL"

> I added "C:\Users\Joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\bin" to my Environmental Variables

> When I return to my code, and run "python example.py" I get the recurring error outlined above.

**TLDR**: ChatterBot example code returns Error regarding OpenSSL. Cannot update it to save my life. Error: "urllib3 v2.0 only supports OpenSSL 1.1.1+, currently the 'ssl' module is compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.0h " **Using Python 3.7**

Comment: The OpenSSL used by builtin 'ssl' (and thus by 'urllib3' and 'requests') is compiled into Python itself and not separately  replacable. **You need a newer Python build** that was compiled with OpenSSL 1.1.1, thus necessarily after Sept. 2018 unlike yours in March 2018 -- **or alternatively a lower urllib3** and maybe requests. 'cryptography' and 'pyOpenSSL' -- only -- use a separate OpenSSL that may be in site-packages or equivalent, and you probably broke them by replacing 3.1 with 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

`pip install urllib3==1.26.6` solved this issue for me